# Trying a backtracking algorithm

Tags: java, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

Ok so I wanted to try and write a backtracking algorithm to solve a simple game. The rules are as follows: There is a triangular board with 5 slots in the top row. There are 5 rows, each row has 1 fewer slot than the row above. Each slot, except for the most bottom row is occupied by a stick. You can remove a stick by taking stick A, jumping over adjacent stick B and plugging A into an empty slot. Doing so will remove stick B from the board. The goal is to have only 1 stick remaining. My code representation is as follows:

```
    private static int[] row1 = {1,1,1,1,1};
    private static int[] row2 =  {1,1,1,1};
    private static int[] row3 =   {1,1,1};
    private static int[] row4 =    {1,1};
    private static int[] row5 =     {0};

    private static int[][] all = {row1,row2,row3,row4,row5};
    private static int value = 14;

    private static List<Move> history = new ArrayList<>();
```

In this starting position, only 2 moves are possible: you can move the first stick in row 3 into row 5, removing the first stick in row 4. Or you move the last stick from row 3 into row 5, removing the last stick in row 4. There are a total of 6 possible moves:
Move a stick topright, topleft, left, right, bottomright and bottomleft.

I have written functions to check whether moving a stick is possible in a given direction. I also wrote functions to move them and to undo the move. Making a move reduces the total number of sticks (value) by 1. Undoing it does the opposite.

My plan now was to write a backtracking algorithm to just try the first possible moves. If the recursive call solves the entire board, it returns true. Else it should backtrack and try the next move.
However, my backtracking always goes back to the start and ends up in a loop, always trying the same set of moves...

This is the function:

```
private static boolean solveBoard(int[][] board){
        if(value == 1){
            return true; //win condition. Making a move reduces the value by 1.
        }
        List<Move> possible = getAllPossibleMoves(board);
        int lastMoveIndex = -1;
        for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++){
                if(possible.size() > 0){// if there are possible moves left, execute the 1st
                    for (Move move : possible) {
                        makeMove(move.getBoard(), move.getRow(), move.getColumn(), move.getDirection());
                        lastMoveIndex = possible.indexOf(move);
                        history.add(move);
                        printBoard(board);
                        if (solveBoard(board)) {
                            return true;
                        } else {// backtrack NOT WORKING
                            for(int m = history.size() -1; m >= lastMoveIndex; m--){
                                undoMove(history.get(m));
                            }
                            history.clear();
                            System.out.println("undo");
                            printBoard(board);
                        }
                    }
                }else if(value != 0){// losing condition: no moves, but more than 1 stick
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for the fun challenge. I see you made a list of possible moves. Each move contains a row and a column. Do you need to loop through each row and column, if you already know them? I don't see where you use `row` and `col`.
Furthermore, clearing the entire history will sabotage earlier recursive calls of your function. They will still need the history that applies to that particular step. You probably only want to remove the moves that failed.

Comment: Ah yes thanks. I don't need the nested for loop anymore. I needed it before I made a Move class that contains the rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Just had to rewirte some methods. If you are interested in the full source code, I'll upload it to github soon.

```
    private static boolean solveBoard(int[][] board, List<Move> possible){
        printBoard(board);
        if(possible.size() == 0){
            return value == 1;
        }
        for(Move move : possible){
            if(solveBoard(makeMove(move),getAllPossibleMoves(makeMove(move)))){
                return true;
            }else{
                undoMove(move);
                printBoard(board);
            }
        }
        return value == 1;
    }
```

Edit: after some more changes, the code is finally on [github](https://github.com/MartinStrotmann/StickGameRecursion)!
Use it as you like.